# Determining players turn in text based noughts and crosses

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am a beginner in Java and for some practise, I am creating a text based noughts and crosses. What I have so far is a Player class, a Board class and a Game class. In the Game class, I have one instance of Board and two instances of Player. I have managed to write code for a player to make a move and to determine whether the game is a win or draw. I now want to ensure that a player can only have one move at a time and not more than one consecutive move i.e Player A, Player B, Player A, Player B...... rather than Player A, Player A, Player A...

The way I thought of doing this was to create a boolean field in the Player class of myTurn and have a method along these lines :

```
public boolean isMyTurn (){
if (myTurn == true){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I then invoke this method in the game glass before I make a move, but for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe I've made a mistake somewhere but if anyone has any other ways/ideas I could write some code to determine if a payers turn is valid or not, please let me know. Would appreciate if you could provide some examples too as I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

I would make the Game class responsible for that. E.g.:

```
class Game {
    ...
    public void makeTurn(){
        if(isFirst)
            firstPlayer.makeTurn();
        else
            secondPlayer.makeTurn();

        isFirst = !isFirst;
    }

    private bool isFirst = true;
    private Player firstPlayer, secondPlayer;
}
```

It even makes sense logically. The player can make many moves one after the other. It's the game (the rules of the game) that prevents him from doing that.

Comment: +1. You can even trivially generalize this to n-players by using a player array and a counter instead of a bool.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, i am a beginner. What I'm finding hard to understand in this code is that firstPlayer and secondPlayer are instances of the Player class. How is it that they can invoke the makeTurn() method because this method exists in the Game class. I tried doing this but i could get playerA (in my case) to call that method. Please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe I didn't understand well your problem, but:

- Who sets myTurn?
- Who "calls" player.play()?

Seems like this should be done by the same guy (a Game/GameManager class?).
So why don't players just play given a description of the game, and you let the task of managing turns to another class?

Cheers

Comment: according to what I have now, the Player class sets myTurn() and and instance of the Player invokes the play method in the games class. Would you have any other suggestions to improve this? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that (overall idea):
1 - Players just play given a description of the state of the game.
2 - Another class (maybe Game) instantiates both players (Player) and the board (Board), and "manages" the game -> calls play to each player in the correct order.

Comment: This is much better, since it leaves the responsibility of managing the game to a Game class, and of playing to the players. With this you can have several implementations of players, and still be free to change the rules of the game. Playing and managing the turns should be independent.

Comment: Thanks for that - That's what i have atm. But going back to my orginal question, in the Game class, how can i determine whos turn it is? dont want one player to have more than 1 go. An example would be appreciated pls. Thanks

Comment: Well, for example, the player class has a method called doMove(Board board), which analyses the board and perform the move. In the game class, you have a boolean that stores the player's turn, for example. You then simply have a while loop that invokes the current player's method, changes the bool and checks if the game is over.